# Fetching 1 product from json file to display on product page

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, next.js, fetch

I am trying to fetch data to display on my product page but i am using a local json file but i don't know how to go about it. here is my 'Item.tsx' file:

```
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { trainers } from '@/helpers'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Heart } from 'lucide-react'

import { ProductType } from '../../type'

interface Product {
  products?: ProductType[]
}

const Item = ({ products }: Product) => {
  console.log(products)
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-rows-4 grid-flow-col gap-4 relative top-5 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-4 mt-10">
      {trainers.map(product => {
        return (
          <div className="relative bg-white px-6 py-9 group border-[1px] border-zinc-200 hover:border-zinc-500 
        duration-300 hover:scale-105 shadow-xl overflow-hidden rounded-lg">
            <Link
              href={{ pathname: `/${product?.id}`, query: { _id: product?.id } }}
            >
              <div key={product.id}>
                <img
                  src={product.image}
                  alt={`Preview of ${product.title}`}
                  width={500}
                  height={500}
                  className="" />
                <div className="py-5 uppercase font-semibold text-center relative top-5">
                  <h3>{product.title}</h3>
                  <p>£{product.price}</p>
                  <button className="hover:text-designColor duration-200 uppercase font-semibold relative top-10 -left-20">
                    Add to Cart
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <Heart fill="black"
              className="absolute bottom-5 right-4 text-zinc-500 w-5 h-5
               hover:text-black cursor-pointer duration-200"
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Item
```

And I want each item to display when clicked on this file:

```
type import { trainers } from "@/helpers"
import { ProductType } from "../../../type"
import Item from "@/components/Item"

type Props = {
    searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}

const page = async ({ searchParams }: any) => {
    const idString = searchParams?.id
    const id = Number(idString)

    const singleProduct = (id: number) => {

    }


    return (
        <div>page</div>
    )
}

export default page
```

This is my 'trainers.json' file (which is imported into my index.ts file in the 'helpers' directory:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Nike Air Force 1",
        "image": "../../../images/trainers/nike_air_force_1.png",
        "id": 101,
        "price": "109.95"
    },
    {
        "title": "Nike Air Force 1",
        "image": "/images/trainers/nike_air_force_1_black.png",
        "id": 102,
        "price": "115.00"
    },
```

index.ts file:

```
import trainers from '@/helpers/trainers.json'

export { trainers }
```

I tried the 'async' function method but that seems to only work when fetching an api, not for local json files.

Any ideas on how to display on product page please? I am also using tailwind.css.